# If a vector contains 3 of 5 elements the return all for that ID == TRUE in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get all id's containing at least three of the five elements c(2,3,4,5,6) to return TRUE for every row of that id, and false for the other ids.

```
id <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3)
time <- c(4,6,4,5,4,5,6,7)
df1 <- data.frame(id,time)
```

Solution

```
solution <-c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
df_w_sol <- data.frame(df1,solution)
```

I'm trying combinations of:

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(INCLUDE = any(2:6 %in% time))
```

But the struggle is the, "at least 3 of the 5" part, which I feel would include n > section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `sum` to count number of values that match :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(solution = sum(2:6 %in% time) >= 3)

#    id  time solution
#  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   
#1     1     4 FALSE   
#2     1     6 FALSE   
#3     2     4 FALSE   
#4     2     5 FALSE   
#5     3     4 TRUE    
#6     3     5 TRUE    
#7     3     6 TRUE    
#8     3     7 TRUE
```

---

The equivalent in base R

```
transform(df1, solution = ave(time, id, FUN = function(x)  sum(2:6 %in% x)) >= 3)
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, solution := sum(2:6 %in% time) >= 3, id]
```

Answer (score 1):

One option could be:

```
df1 %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(include = n_distinct(match(time, 2:6)) >= 3)

     id  time include
  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>  
1     1     4 FALSE  
2     1     6 FALSE  
3     2     4 FALSE  
4     2     5 FALSE  
5     3     4 TRUE   
6     3     5 TRUE   
7     3     6 TRUE   
8     3     7 TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `length` with `intersect`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(solution = length(intersect(time, 2:6))>=3)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   id [3]
#    id  time solution
#  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>   
#1     1     4 FALSE   
#2     1     6 FALSE   
#3     2     4 FALSE   
#4     2     5 FALSE   
#5     3     4 TRUE    
#6     3     5 TRUE    
#7     3     6 TRUE    
#8     3     7 TRUE
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)   
setDT(df1)[, solution := length(intersect(time, 2:6))>=3, id]
```